# How to initialise an array in Java with a constant value efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Is there a way to initialise an array of integers (or possibly any array) to a constant value other than zero (or null) which are the defaults, without a for loop?

Ideally I am looking for a function like "ones" in matlab, which is not only neater but also more efficient.

Comment: Such methods almost always use loops.  A reason it could be faster in Matlab is that its an interpreted language whereas Java can be compiled to native code. Ironically, some loops in java can be so heavily optimised they are faster than using native calls. e.g. a loop to copy `long[]` can be faster using a loop than using `System.arrayCopy`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Arrays.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is the method you're after. (Although internally it still uses a for loop, so unlike `System.arrayCopy()`, it isn't any faster.)

P.s.: `Arrays`, and its collection-based counterpart `Collections` are two extremely useful classes in general.

Comment: It may be faster in some implementations since the JITC knows it can bypass bounds checks.

Comment: It may be, but I don't know of any JIT implementations out there that treat the same code in a different way just because it's in `java.util. Do you know a specific JIT that does this?

Comment: Well, I once worked on a JITC that did so, and I think the more advanced Sun/Oracle JITCs do something similar, based on indirect evidence.

Comment: Many low-level routines in java. packages are intrinsified by the JIT, so that the "reference" implementation you see in the JDK source may never be executed.

You can check the list of intrinsics [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/3facbb14e873/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp) (look for *Here are all the intrinsics*).  It doesn't seem to include Arrays.fill currently, but does include other methods from Arrays.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful knowledge.